# Unable to run selenium suite on firefox 17

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

My suite was running fine in firefox-16. Updated the firefox version to 17.  But my test cases fail throwing the following exception. My selenium webdriver version is 2.26.0. My test suite is in ruby.

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN8
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18041', time: '2012-11-01 19:33:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException).

If I try to run on webdriver 2.25.0, my test suite just hangs in the middle of execution. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade Firefox slightly. The current version of Selenium does not support v17, although looking at the commit changes here, you can see they have fixed it, presumably ready for v2.27:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/list

You can download an older version of Firefox from here:

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

or

http://www.oldapps.com/firefox.php

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Selenium 2.28.0 and FireFox 17 should be supported.